# Is there a way to format data from MySQL on SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of numbers like these:

```
100
25000
-5
-20
1
```

And I would like to have them formatted to look like this when pulling the data out:

```
100.00
25,000.00
(5.00)
(20.00)
1.00
```

Is there any way to do the formatting via the MySQL SELECT statement? Or should I be doing that elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seldom a good idea to have MySQL doing any formatting. That's not what MySQL is good at — let the DBMS give you data, and let your program figure out how to present the data.

The major danger of formatting numbers within a query is that you've permanently linked the data with the presentation. If you ever decided you wanted to do any math with those numbers, you'd have to go to the trouble of un-formatting the data in your program — so you'd be right back at having the application do formatting work, but now in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers, you can use FORMAT() function in the SELECT statement, but it is very limited. I suggest writing your own parser/formatter in the Model layer.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mathematical-format.php